# Don't allow duplicate value records in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

When user adding details to a dictionary, I want check those details are already there or not,
When name, age, team and car have same values in another record ignore those inputs and tell the user "It's already there" otherwise "add" details to the dictionary. Also, this duplication check should happen before appending to the List.
I don't how to do this I tried but it doesn't work

```
driver_list = []

name = str(input("Enter player name : "))
try:
   age = int(input("Enter the age : "))
except ValueError:
   print("Input an integer",)
   age = int(input("Enter the age : "))
team = str(input("Enter team name : "))
car = str(input("Enter name of the car : "))
try:
   current_points = int(input("Enter the current points of the player : "))
except ValueError:
   print("Input an integer")
   current_points = int(input("Enter the current points of the player : "))
     
driver_details={"Name":name ,"Age": age,"Team": team ,"Car": car, "Current_points": current_points}
driver_list.append(driver_details)
```

Comment: While this does not answer your question, I do have a recommendation related to your code. You should probably create a function for integer input, and perhaps another one for string input. This way you can handle all the errors in a centralised manner, without having to repeat the error checks EVERY time you request information from the user.

Answer (score 2):

```
# check all values in the driver_det is found in any of the 
# dictionaries in the list driver_list
def checkAllInList(driver_det): 
    # define the keys we are interested in
    Interest = ['name', 'age', 'team', 'car']
    # get corresponding values from the driver_det
    b = set([value for key, value in driver_det.items() if key in Interest])
    
    # iterate over all driver_list dictionaries
    for d in driver_list:
        # get all values corresponding to the interest keys for the d driver
        a = set([value for key, value in d.items() if key in Interest])
        # if both have the same values, return true
        if a == b:
            return True; # if found equal, return true
    return False; #otherwise, return false if non of the dictionaries have these details

#  you can use it like that
if checkAllInList(driver_details):   # check a duplicate is found
    print("this is a duplicate value")
else:                                # no duplicate found
    driver_list.append(driver_details)
```